# On hiding iPad keyboard, HTML form field values are pre-populated even after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, keyboard, bootstrap-typeahead

We have a HTML form with 2 fields. On signing in using signIn button or GO button of iPad keyboard, it displays a message in the same pop-up. On displaying message we have to clear or reset the values previously entered.

I'm resetting using: `$('#kLoginForm')[0].reset();`

It is clearing the fields and on hiding the iPad keyboard manually, the values are pre populated again, which should not happen.

Comment: And did you check if it isn't some sort of autofill? If no, then use the `autocomplete="off"` tag in your inputs and see if this "error" still occurs.

Comment: We are using typeahead for one inputfield which is pre populating@ jPO

Comment: I don't know what that is, but nevermind. I asked whether you tried  to disable the autocomplete. It wouldn't disable the typeahead, but it would prevent the browser on ipad from pre-filling the fields maybe? And a piece of code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using typeahead then you have to clear the fields like this:

```
$('#fieldName').typeahead('setQuery', '');
```

So it will nullify that value.